# Django: "state" is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add inputs on my application where a user can put in their "age", "city", and "state". It already worked for "first_name", "last_name", and "email", but when I added these fields I got this error thrown at me.

Person Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """ The model which defines a user of the application. Contains important
    information like name, email, city/state, age, etc """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

View for creating an account:

```
def create_account(request):
    # function to allow a user to create their own account
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # sets a new user and gives them a username
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"],
                    email=request.POST["email"],
                    first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                    last_name=request.POST["last_name"],
                    age=request.POST["age"],
                    city=request.POST["city"],
                    state=request.POST["state"])
        # sets an encrypted password
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        # adds the new user to the database
        Person.objects.create(user=new_user,
                          first_name=str(request.POST.get("first_name")),
                          last_name=str(request.POST.get("last_name")),
                          email=str(request.POST.get("email")),
                          age=str(request.POST.get("age")),
                          city=str(request.POST.get("city")),
                          state=str(request.POST.get("state")))
        new_user.is_active = True
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: You should be using a form here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `state` field in `User` model but you tried to pass it when you create `new_user`.

Comment: I tried replacing User(...) with Person(...) and that didn't yield any results. How do I get around this?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You created a user then you assign that user to a `Person` object that's what I can see. How can you replace `User` with a `Person`? They are 2 different models.

Comment: I guess a better question is, how do I extend the User model to have additional attributes like "age", "city", and "state"?

Comment: Django has dedicated doc to explain this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!