# Django: Add additional properties to User

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add additional attributes to my "Person" model, namely, "age", "city", and "state." I've been struggling with this for a few days now and have looked up the documentation on how to "Extend the User class" in Django. But, I'm stuck, and when I try to create a new account I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /polls/signup/add
'age' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Create account view (I'm pretty sure this is where the problem is occurring):

```
def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"],
                    email=request.POST["email"],
                    first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                    last_name=request.POST["last_name"],
                    age=request.POST["age"],
                    city=request.POST["city"],
                    state=request.POST["state"])
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        Person.objects.create(user=new_user,
                          first_name=str(request.POST.get("first_name")),
                          last_name=str(request.POST.get("last_name")),
                          email=str(request.POST.get("email")),
                          age=str(request.POST.get("age")),
                          city=str(request.POST.get("city")),
                          state=str(request.POST.get("state")))
        new_user.is_active = True
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem and allow users to add these bonus fields that aren't included with the generic User model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: "state" is an invalid keyword argument for this function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954270/django-state-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-function)

Comment: I'm still having this issue so I made another question. I think you actually commented on the old post as well, haha.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is confusing you. Those fields only exist on Person, not User; you should send only the fields that are on User to User, and the ones that are on Person to Person.

Comment: I understand the concept. That is completely clear to me. It's just the syntax and how to actually write it that confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Person model instead of User.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"],
                    email=request.POST["email"],
                    first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                    last_name=request.POST["last_name"],
                    )
    new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
    new_user.save()
    Person.objects.create(user=new_user,
                      age=str(request.POST.get("age")),
                      city=str(request.POST.get("city")),
                      state=str(request.POST.get("state")))
    new_user.is_active = True
    new_user.save()
    return redirect('../')
else:
    return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Comment: That fixed the error messages. Now, the only problem is that the information isn't displaying. But, I've dealt with a similar problem. Thanks!